# Understanding animationItemBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to understand the following code in Flutter:

```
Widget Function(BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation)

animationItemBuilder(Widget Function(int index) child,
    {EdgeInsets padding = EdgeInsets.zero}) =>
        (BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) =>
        FadeTransition(
          opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(animation),
          child: SlideTransition(
            position:
            Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, -0.1), end: Offset.zero)
                .animate(animation),
            child: Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: child(index),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I'm clearly new to Flutter and i've tried to understand the code above. In my example the method "animationItemBuilder" is called on the LiveList class in the itemBuilder method.

Comment: have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Widget Function(BuildContext context, int index, Animation
> animation)

Is the return type of function

> animationItemBuilder(Widget Function(int index) child,
> {EdgeInsets padding = EdgeInsets.zero})

Is the function name and a list of parameters.

```
(BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) =>
        FadeTransition(
          opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(animation),
          child: SlideTransition(
            position:
            Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, -0.1), end: Offset.zero)
                .animate(animation),
            child: Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: child(index),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Is the returned value.

So basically, this defines a function named animationItemBuilder which returns another function.

And yes, it is very complicated.

Comment: So if i call the function animationItemBuilder on the LiveList class and use "animationItemBuilder(index)", it means that the index is used like a callback to the function and the code  `Widget Function(int index) child`  is only used to call the Widget Function to store the position (index) in there?

Comment: The first param of animationItemBuilder (child) is a function, so you need to pass a function there. Later "child" will be used to generate the widget in the body. "child: child(index)" the generated widget go there.

Comment: I think i've understood it although its very hard to comprehend